# How to create a search bar and list (created with StreamBuilder and Listview from FireStore) scroll together?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, scroll, stream-builder

I'm relatively new to flutter/dart, and I'm trying to get the formatting on one of my pages working. I would like to have a search bar at the top followed by a list (filled with information from Firestore), and I want to have them scroll together rather than just the list.

Here's a section of my code so far:

```
  return Column (children: <Widget>[
    TextField(
        controller: _controller,
        onSubmitted: (String value) async {
          await showDialog<void>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: const Text('Thanks!'),
                content: Text('You typed "$value".'),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: const Text('OK'),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        }),
    Expanded(child: buildLearnCards(context))
  ]);
}

Widget buildLearnCards(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder(
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I will attempt to give a broad description of how to implement this as it requires a bit of infrastructure and knowledge of State Management. I would recommend using [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) to manage state. In the constructor of your provider/model, retrieve the list of documents from Firestore and store it in a List. Then use this [tutorial](https://blog.usejournal.com/flutter-search-in-listview-1ffa40956685) to filter your documents based off the search text field. Every time the `filterSearchResults` method is called, call `notifyListeners()` at the end of your function. Then in your list of documents in your widget use a `Consumer` as mentioned in [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) tutorial to retrieve the list of documents from your provider and display in a `ListView` however you want. Hope it helps, and ask any questions if you are coming across issues.